# RxJS: Removing fields from an object

Tags: rxjs

Lets say I have an object with 4 fields like this:

```
obj = {a:"3", b:"7", c:"10", d:"123"}
```

and I need to 'narrow' it to an object with fewer fields, like that:

```
newObj = {a:"3", c:"10"}
```

I know this can be done by deleting the fields (ie. delete obj.b )

My question is, can this be done with RxJS? And if yes, how???

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you looking to mutate an existing object or would it also fit your case to have a new object as the result?

Comment: As a short answer: No, there is no such thing as `delete attributes` in RxJS

Comment: Really?? This is the first time I encounter something can't be done with RxJS.. Back to good old tactics then.. Thanks man!

Comment: You can of course map to a new object - that's why I asked the first question - my other question would be: Why you try to replace something native (like in this case `delete`) with some library-function? In the best-case that rxjs-method would just call `delete` anyways.

Answer (score 3):

You if you have an `Observable`, that emits the shape above, you can do something like this:

```
Rx.Observable.of({ a:"3", b:"7", c:"10", d:"123" })
  .map(({ a, c }) => ({ a, c }))
```

In the mapping function I destructure the object, then create an object literal with the shorthand syntax. Mind that these are es6/7 features.

But you really don't need rxjs or Observables to do this:

```
const original = { a:"3", b:"7", c:"10", d:"123" }
const changed = { a: original.a, c: original.c }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **remove specific fields from the object (or stream of objects)**, rather than keeping specific ones, then you can use the following operator:

```js
const removeFieldsOp = (props)=>obs=>obs.pipe(map(({...o})=>
(props.forEach(prop=>delete o[prop]), o)));

of({ a:"3", b:"7", c:"10", d:"123" }).pipe(removeFieldsOp(['b','d']))
.subscribe(console.log);

//{ a: '3', c: '10' }
```